# Octopress - rendered as mobile in IE8 and "navigate" has "undefined". How to fix it?

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, octopress

I have re-built my web site using Ocopress. 
I found it really great for building static site!

BUT the problem now is - that **when I try to see in in Internet Explorer 8 - it has a "Mobile" look!** I mean - that **IE8 is thought to be mobile**. And it's not. Al least not for me...

In addition - **the "navigate" drop-down has "undefined" entries**.

I use IE8 from time to time at my work PC (even though I prefer Firefox and Chrome / Chromium).

See the image I'm attaching - My Octopress site with IE8.  [1]

Compare to how my Octopress site looks in Firefox (looks good!): [2]

Compare it to how my Octopress site looks in Google Chrome (also good!)

1. My site on IE8 (not good):
   http://www.flickr.com/photos/meorero/8657827234/
2. Firefox (good):
   http://www.flickr.com/photos/meorero/8656722709/

Comment: Not really enough information here for us to help. We at least need to see your site or an example of what's going wrong.

Comment: Hi @Spudley . My web site is: http://www.meorero.org.il . 

I have also tried to ass into my question links to screenshots that I uploaded to Flickr - see above. 

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There's a few issues going on here in <= ie8 as I found with my octopress site.

(I'm using Octopress v2.0 as cloned from the master branch on March-11-2013)

- the site uses html5 tags
- the upgrade to Modernizr 2.6 drops respond.js which means the site always looks like the mobile version
- and the navigate dropdown labels don't work in any ie versions

So, The following worked for me on my site:

1. Add

   ```
   <!--[if lt IE 9]>
       <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
       <script src="{{ root_url }}/javascripts/libs/respond.min.js"></script>
   <![endif]-->
   ```

   to `source/_includes/head.html` before the `</head>` tag
2. Get the `respond.min.js` file

   `git clone https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond.git`

   and put it in `source/javascripts/libs`

This should fix the styling and media query problem for <= ie8

1. To fix the navigate drop down will need to fix the use of link.text attribute in octopress.js. The version of octopress I cloned includes jquery so:

   in `source/javascripts/octopress.js` make the changes to getNav() as indicated below, replacing `link.text` with `$(link).text()` as IE uses innerText rather than text attribute on the links.

   Heres the change set diff:

   ```
   @@ -3,10 +3,10 @@
      mobileNav.children('select').append('<option value="">Navigate&hellip;</option>');
      $('ul[role=main-navigation]').addClass('main-navigation');
      $('ul.main-navigation a').each(function(i, link) {
   -    mobileNav.children('select').append('<option value="'+link.href+'">&raquo; '+link.text+'</option>');
   +    mobileNav.children('select').append('<option value="'+link.href+'">&raquo; '+$(link).text()+'</option>');
      });
      $('ul.subscription a').each(function(i, link) {
   -    mobileNav.children('select').append('<option value="'+link.href+'">&raquo; '+link.text+'</option>');
   +    mobileNav.children('select').append('<option value="'+link.href+'">&raquo; '+$(link).text()+'</option>');
      });
      mobileNav.children('select').bind('change', function(event) {
        if (event.target.value) { window.location.href = event.target.value; }
   ```

The octopress issue tracking is closed on github for the moment so some or all of these things will hopefully be fixed by the next release.

Comment: Champion. This was exactly what I was looking for. The `octopress.js` file is slightly different in 2.1, but the change you described did the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did - this seems to work for Desktop browsers - **including IE8** !!:

In ./source/_includes/head.html

Deleted this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if IEMobile 7 ]><html class="no-js iem7"><![endif]-->
<!--[if lt IE 9]><html class="no-js lte-ie8"><![endif]-->
<!--[if (gt IE 8)|(gt IEMobile 7)|!(IEMobile)|!(IE)]><!--><html class="no-js" lang="en">
<!--<![endif]-->
<head>
```

And put this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]> <html lang="en" class="no-js ie6"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7 ]> <html lang="en" class="no-js ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]> <html lang="en" class="no-js ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--> <html lang="en" class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
```

Comment: Well... I try to re-open this post. 
At home PC with IE9 - my site looks OK. 

BUT at my work PC - with IE8 - the site still looks bad, and quite broken , so... the above did not really help :-(